# Pattern regex in HTML5 prevent white space?

Tags: regex, html, validation

I have regex for two different fields. Both will evaluate correct values but none of them prevents user of entering white space. For example in Gender field user can simply enter white space and submit the form. I want to prevent user of entering white space. Here is my regex:

```
Gender pattern="*[MmFf]?*"  #This field should allow M or F letter lower or upper case. Nothing else should be allowed. This field is 1 character only.

Grade pattern=" *(0?[0-9]|1[0-2]|[A-Z]{1,2})? *" #This should allow 01 or 1 and something like this PK or pk. No white space.
```

I'm not sure how to prevent white space in HTML5 pattern. if anyone knows how to solve this problem please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to prevent white spaces in a regular expression regex validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842823/how-to-prevent-white-spaces-in-a-regular-expression-regex-validation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your patterns allow spaces ( `*`) or empty strings. Make the patterns match at least something:

- *Gender*: `pattern="[MmFf]"`
- *Grade*: `pattern="0?[0-9]|1[0-2]|[A-Za-z]{1,2}"`

Mind that HTML5 patterns do not require explicit `^` and `$` anchors (unless some unusual framework overrides the HTML5 `pattern` behavior).

So, the first pattern will be translated to `^(?:[MmFf])$` pattern and will only match a string that is equal to `M`, `m`, `F` or `f`.

The second one will be translated into `^(?:0?[0-9]|1[0-2]|[A-Za-z]{1,2})$` and will match  a string (requiring a full string match)

- `0?[0-9]` - an optional `0` followed with a digit
- `|` - or
- `1[0-2]`  - `10`, `11` or `12`
- `|` - or
- `[A-Za-z]{1,2}` - 1 or 2 upper- or lowercase ASCII letters

Comment: how to allow [A-Z]{1,2} - 1 or 2 uppercase ASCII letters lower case as well in this combination?

Comment: @espresso_coffee Just add `a-z` to the character class.

Comment: That part is the same like in regular regex. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: pattern="[a-zA-Z][A-Za-z' .,-]{0,29}$" this should allow letter upper lower case with special charters .,' - and not be longer than 30 charters but at the same time not to be empty. Does that looks correct?

Comment: If you mean it should start with a letter then yes, `pattern="[a-zA-Z][A-Za-z' .,-]{0,29}"` is OK. It also allows `a-` and `"A "` (space at the end).

Comment: If I want to allow 4 digits only does this looks correct "d{4}"?

Comment: No idea what you mean. To match a string that only contains 4 consecutive digits, `pattern="\d{4}"` will work OK.

Comment: yes that's what I meant. Thanks. Just checking my expressions. All of them, work fine in my server side language but in HTML5 I have no experience.